# Issue in incrementing int i for syncall task

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-fragments

Here is my code:

```
 private void syncall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (i < synclist.size()) {
        Log.i("iiiiiiiiiiii", "" + i+"Synclist"+synclist.size());
        View vi = getViewByPosition(i, lst);
        txt_master = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_master);
        txt_update = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_lastupdate);
        prg_sync = (ProgressBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.prog);
        table_name = txt_master.getText().toString();
        name = txt_master.getText().toString();
        if (table_name.equalsIgnoreCase("IP")) {
            table_name = "tbl_All_Iplist";
        } else if (table_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Pickup")) {
            table_name = "tbl_Onlinepickup";
        } else {
            table_name = "tbl_" + table_name;
            table_name = table_name.replace(" ", "");
        }
        final SharedPreferences Ipconfig = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Ipconfig",
                Serverconfiguration.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ip = Ipconfig.getString("ip", "");

        final SharedPreferences login = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("login",
                FvrActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mUrlWebServicesync = "http://" + ip + "/apis/service/"
                + synclist_tag.get(i)
                .concat("?employeeId=")
                .concat(login.getString(
                        "empid", ""));
        Log.i("url", "" + mUrlWebServicesync);


        pdialog.setMessage("sync " + name);

        new Calllwebservice_sync().execute();
    } else {

        try {
            if ((pdialog != null) && pdialog.isShowing())
                pdialog.dismiss();
            pdialog = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("", "" + e);
        }

        pdialog_active = false;
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent("refresh_sync_sec"));
        click_sync = 0;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

And here is asynctask code:

```
 public class Calllwebservice_sync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("db_focus", getActivity().MODE_APPEND, null);

            JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray(responseJSON);
            for(int k=0;k<jarr.length();k++){
                JSONObject jobj=jarr.getJSONObject(0);
                String mdetails=jobj.getString("details");
                if(mdetails.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    JSONObject jobj1=jarr.getJSONObject(1);

                    cur = db.rawQuery("select * from " + table_name + ";", null);
                    int cnt = cur.getCount();
                    Log.i("Count", ""+cnt);
                    if (cnt != 0) {
                        db.execSQL("delete from " + table_name + ";");
                    }
                    JSONArray jarr1=jobj1.getJSONArray("details");

                    for (int j=0;j<jarr1.length();j++){
                        JSONObject jobj2=jarr1.getJSONObject(j);
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Code")) {
                            Log.e("Hello", "hello");
                            db.execSQL("insert into "
                                    + table_name
                                    + " values('"
                                    + jobj2.getString("CODE_ID")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("CODE")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("CLIENT_ID")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("CLIENT_NAME")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("ADD_IN_FCR")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("ADD_IN_FVR")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("ADD_IN_FRR")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("RQUIRE_FOLLOWUP")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("FOLLOWUP_MENDATORY")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("FOLLOWUP_REMARK") + "');");


                        }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Product")){
                            Log.e("Hello", "hello1");
                            db.execSQL("insert into "
                                    + table_name
                                    + " values('"
                                    + jobj2.getString("PRODUCT_ID")
                                    + "','"
                                    + jobj2.getString("PRODUCT_NAME")
                                    + "');");
                        }
                    }
                    WebServiceCall webServiceCall = new WebServiceCall();
                    webServiceCall.cleardata();
                    responseJSON = null;

                    if (flag == 1) {
                        i++;
                        // prg_sync.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        handler.removeCallbacks(run_sync);
                        syncall();
                        Log.e("hello", ""+i);

                    }else {
                        try {

                            Log.e("hello", "1234");
                            if ((pdialog != null) && pdialog.isShowing())
                                pdialog.dismiss();
                            pdialog = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i("", "" + e);
                        }

                        pdialog_active = false;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(run_sync);
                        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent("refresh_sync_sec"));
                    }

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            name + " Sync Data Not Available",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    handler.removeCallbacks(run_sync);
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        i++;
                        syncall();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            if ((pdialog != null) && pdialog.isShowing())
                                pdialog.dismiss();
                            pdialog = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i("", "" + e);
                        }
                        pdialog_active = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
 //        
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    name + " Sync Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            // prg_sync.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            handler.removeCallbacks(run_sync);
            if (flag == 1) {
                i++;
                syncall();
            } else {
                try {
                    if ((pdialog != null) && pdialog.isShowing())
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    pdialog = null;
                } catch (Exception f) {
                    Log.i("", "" + f);
                }
                pdialog_active = false;
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        name + " Sync Data Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            // prg_sync.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            handler.removeCallbacks(run_sync);
            if (flag == 1) {
                i++;
                syncall();

            } else {
                try {
                    if ((pdialog != null) && pdialog.isShowing())
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    pdialog = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("", "" + e);
                }
                pdialog_active = false;
            }
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

log error :

```
  I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 1Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:51.974 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 2Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.051 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 1Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.254 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 2Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.339 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 1Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.545 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 2Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.630 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 1Synclist3
  01-06 12:36:52.861 26944-26944/com.wp.focus I/iiiiiiiiiiii: 2Synclist3
```

Issue is at log **iiiiiiiiiii the 0 number repeating instead of incrementing as initial value of i is 0** and at **hello in flag==1 the i value is incremented by 1 but in syncall again its value is 0 not getting whats the issue...** thank you in advance

Comment: You're incrementing a local variable, not the same `i` referenced in `syncall()`.

Comment: no i is global int variable whose value is 0 in the beginning @shmosel

Comment: There may be another global variable `i`, but it's hidden by the local `i` in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: in `syncall` you do `i = 0;`

Comment: Also as per @shmosel `for(int i=0...`

Comment: yeah I got it @shmosel bt there is now another issue I had changed for loop i into int k but now issue is again loop is going infinite....I had editted my question instead of i had taken k....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the `i`'s are two different counters. The `i` in `syncall()` is never incremented.

Try changing every occurrence of `i` in the second block of code with `j`, and running the code again. If `j` is incremented but `i` is not, we have our answer.